# Automatically fill data in datagridview in windows based application

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 4 columns. In first column,there is a textbox and the value is coming from the checkedlistbox ie outside the datagridview. Now in second column there is a combobox and in that value is manually filled. And in third column there is textbox and i'll fill the value and after that in fourth column,the value will be (column2 * column 3)  ie automatically come after the calculation. So how can i fill value automatically in column fourth. please help me.

Comment: is your DataGridView databound?

Answer (score 0):

To make it dynamically change, you should handle some event, also make some `init` method to initialize the grid:

```
//CellValueChanged event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){ 
  var col = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
  if(col.Name == "column2" || col.Name == "column3") {
    //update the column4
    dataGridView1[dataGridView1.Columns["column4"].Index, e.RowIndex].Value = 
    dataGridView1[dataGridView1.Columns["column2"].Index, e.RowIndex].Value *
    dataGridView1[dataGridView1.Columns["column3"].Index, e.RowIndex].Value;
  }         
}
//use this method to initialize all the values for the `column4`, this will be done only
//once in ,for example, your Form constructor
private void InitColumn4(){
   foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows){
     if(row.IsNewRow) continue;
     row.Cells["column4"].Value = row.Cells["column2"].Value * row.Cells["column3"].Value;
   }
}
//call it in your form constructor
public Form1(){ 
   InitializeComponent();
   //init data for your grid first
   //...
   InitColumn4();
}
```

**NOTE**: I suppose your columns have names `"column2"`, `"column3"`, `"column4"` respectively. Using column name is better because you may change your column index unexpectedly and your code will be broken and the code is also more readable.